# How to receive paypal payment confirmation?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to identify in Paypal whether a successful payment has been made or not using IPN messages. I have the listener script on the server and I set the URL for the listener on Paypal along with enabling the notification. However I'm receiving "Invalid" response whenever I refresh the listener page. I know that I'm doing something incorrectly I just can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: I know you already mentioned that you configured IPN listener, but I didn't understand refreshing the listener page and getting the "invalid".. are you using sandbox mode??

Comment: No. I'm testing it in a live environment...I don't really know how to identify that a payment has been done. Where will the result be shown? That's why I'm refreshing the listener page on the server as maybe this is where the result will show whether it's valid or not.

Comment: also you can try https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator to test your IPN listener

Comment: Bro, seriously I will recommend you to test the things with sandbox IF YOU ARE NOT RICH, then go for live.. you can do many transaction there..

Comment: Create Seller and Buyer accounts at sandbox.paypal.com; specify URL to your IPN listener in seller's account and test it as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the following link you will get idea (**Paypal**)

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt

http://ebusinessebooks.com/ipnscript.php

http://www.softcoded.com/articles/paypal_hack1.php

https://www.paypal.com/ipn